# First console.log (obj), then add attributes to obj, why can print out the attribute?

Tags: javascript

```js
var obj = {
  b: 2
};
console.log(obj.a);
console.log(obj);
obj.a = 1;
console.log(obj);
```

The three console.log() outputs the following results:

[image: img1]

The first `undefined` I can understand, but the second one can output `a:1`, and it can be seen that the second and third printing results have a distinct difference:

Why has the first parenthesis only `b:2`, and the second full output?

Comment: As you can see, the console-output is not as you stated.

Comment: *"Why has the first parenthesis only b:2, and the second full output?"* Because at the moment you are logging the object the first time, it only has a single property. When you log it a second time it has two properties.

Comment: Expanding the object in the console shows the state of the object at the time you expanded it.

Comment: @Wen-Sun Check the blue i tooltip. The values are updated by not the header.